# Ignore words with punctuation when replacing them in text file using dictionary

Tags: python

I have the a text file with multiple lines. I need to use a dictionary to replace words in that text file with new ones.

I need to exclude words with punctuation on them (e.g. cat! dance?).

I need to save the results in a new text file and also keep the formatting of the original one.

Here is what I have been trying to do so far in Python.

The result I want is a new text file with the following three lines:

I love my cat!

I love to drink water

Do I really want to dance?

```
#--create my custom dictionary 

mydict = {
  "cat": "dog",
  "milk": "water", #--mistakenly had these switched in original post
  "dance": "sit"
}

#--import list of punctuations

from string import punctuation

#--create sample data 

f=open("mytextfile.txt", "w+")
f.write("I love my cat!" + "\n" + "I love to drink milk" + "\n" + "Do I really want to dance?" + "\n") 
f.close()

#--read in sample data

i = open("mytextfile.txt", "r")

txtfile = i.read()

i.close

#print(txtfile)

#--create an empty list for new textfile

new_txtfile = []

#--for loop through each sentence

for line in txtfile:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        new_word = []
        if word in punctuation:
            new_word = word #--do not replace word if it is punctuated
        else:
            new_word = mydict.get(word) #--replace word using dictionary
    new_line= '\n'.join(new_word)
    new_textfile.append(new_line)
    
print(new_txtfile)

#--save the new textfile 
#--make sure the new lines are preserved

with open("my_new_file.txt", 'w') as file:
        for row in new_textfile:
            s = " ".join(map(str, row))
            file.write(s+'\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to consider punctuation because, for example, 'cat!' is not equal to 'cat'. So, all you need is this:

```
INFILE = "mytextfile.txt"
OUTFILE = "my_new_file.txt"

mydict = {
  "cat": "dog",
  "water": "milk",
  "dance": "sit"
}

with open(INFILE, "w") as txt:
    print("I love my cat!", file=txt)
    print("I love to drink milk", file=txt)
    print("Do I really want to dance?", file=txt)

with open(INFILE) as txt, open(OUTFILE, 'w') as newtext:
    for line in map(str.strip, txt):
        words = line.split()
        for i, word in enumerate(words):
            if (replacement := mydict.get(word)) is not None:
                words[i] = replacement
        print(' '.join(words), file=newtext)
```

**Output (file content):**

```
I love my cat!
I love to drink milk
Do I really want to dance?
```

**Note:**

Of course, given the dictionary as shown in the question, this won't modify the file because none of the keys (words) will match

Comment: thanks for responding to my question. I made a mistake in my original post for the dictionary, and had the key value pair of milk and water reversed. Your solution works once I fix that issue. I chose your solution over the other ones here because I am able to more easily preserve the formatting of the original file.

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove extra characters (i.e. `\n`) and check if there is a match between the word in the dict and if so then map it across. If there is punctation then the word will not match - so we do not need a separate rule for this. `"cat" != "dog"` but also `"cat!" != "cat`.

```py
#--create my custom dictionary 

my_dict = {
  "cat": "dog",
  "water": "milk",
  "dance": "sit"
}

#--import list of punctuations

from string import punctuation

#--create sample data 

with open("mytextfile.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write("I love my cat!" + "\n" + "I love to drink milk" + "\n" + 
    "Do I really want to dance?" + "\n") 

#--read in sample data

with open("mytextfile.txt", "r") as i:
    txtfile = i.readlines()

#print(txtfile)

#--create an empty list for new textfile

new_txtfile = []

#--for loop through each sentence

for line in txtfile:
    print(line)
    words = line.replace("\n", "").split(" ")
    print(words)
    for index, word in enumerate(words):
        new_word = []
        if word in my_dict.keys():
            print(f'replacing {word} with {my_dict[word]}')
            words[index] = my_dict[word]
        elif word in my_dict.values():
            for key, value in my_dict.items():
                if word == value:
                    words[index] = key
    words[-1] = words[-1]  + "\n"
    new_txtfile.append(" ".join(words))


#--save the new textfile 
#--make sure the new lines are preserved

with open("my_new_file.txt", 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(new_txtfile)
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, you forgot add bracket in `i.close`.

Comment: @JacekK Correct - this was a direct copy from OPs code. Updated such that it uses `with` for the opens as this is programmatically better imo.

Comment: @JeremySavage thanks for trying to answer my question. I made a mistake in my original post for the dictionary, and had the key value pair of milk and water reversed. Your solution works! I want to ask, what happens to the empty list new_word you created? I don't see values assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot brackets in your close method. Should be `i.close()` insted `i.close`. The best practise is using a context manager instead of open/close methods. [Read more.](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/)
Also you try append to non existing list `new_textfile` instead `new_txtfile`.

Bellow you will find solution with comments:

```
from string import punctuation # [1]
    
mydict = {
    "cat": "dog",
    "milk": "water", # [2]
    "dance": "sit"
}

with open("mytextfile.txt", "w+") as f: # [3]
    f.write("I love my cat!" + "\n" + "I love to drink milk" + "\n" + "Do I really want to dance?" + "\n")

new_txtfile = []

with open("mytextfile.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        words = line.replace("\n", "").split()
        for index, word in enumerate(words):
            if mydict.get(word) and word[-1] not in punctuation: # [4]]
                words[index] = mydict.get(word)
        new_txtfile.append(" ".join(words))

with open("my_new_file.txt", 'w') as file:
    file.write("\n".join(new_txtfile))
```

1. All import should be on the top of file. [Read more.](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports)
2. I replaced value and key here. It has more sense in this case.
3. Replaced open/close by context manager to avoid errors (like missing brackets ;) )
4. I checked if the word is in the dict. If yes, and the last character is not punctationa I finding index for this word and in `words` list i replace word with this index using result from the dict

the final file otput:

```
I love my cat!
I love to drink water
Do I really want to dance?
```

Comment: thanks for catching my mistake with the dictionary entry for milk and water. I tried your solution and it works!